# Combining Two Vectors of References into a Vector of Values Without Consuming an Iterator in Rust

Tags: vector, rust, combinations, rust-itertools

I'm currently working with Rust and I'm trying to combine two vectors of references into a single vector of values, without consuming an iterator.

Here's the situation: I'm generating vectors by iterating over specific combinations (2 elements from one vector, 2 elements from another vector).

Here's the code I'm currently working with:

```rust
use core::iter::Iterator;
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let vec_a: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let vec_b: Vec<u8> = vec![4, 5, 6];

    // a: Vec<&u8>
    for a in vec_a.iter().combinations(2) {
        // b: Vec<&u8>
        for b in vec_b.iter().combinations(2) {
            // c: Vec<u8> <- a + b
            let c: Vec<u8> = a.clone().into_iter().chain(b).cloned().collect();
            println!("a: {:?}, b: {:?}, c: {:?}", a, b, c);
        }
    }
}
```

The expected output is as follows:

```
a: [1, 2], b: [4, 5], c: [1, 2, 4, 5]
a: [1, 2], b: [4, 6], c: [1, 2, 4, 6]
a: [1, 2], b: [5, 6], c: [1, 2, 5, 6]
a: [1, 3], b: [4, 5], c: [1, 3, 4, 5]
a: [1, 3], b: [4, 6], c: [1, 3, 4, 6]
a: [1, 3], b: [5, 6], c: [1, 3, 5, 6]
a: [2, 3], b: [4, 5], c: [2, 3, 4, 5]
a: [2, 3], b: [4, 6], c: [2, 3, 4, 6]
a: [2, 3], b: [5, 6], c: [2, 3, 5, 6]
```

I've reviewed the following StackOverflow post: [Best way to concatenate vectors in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40792801/best-way-to-concatenate-vectors-in-rust), but the solution provided there consumes the Vec and its iterator, which doesn't work in my case.

Could anyone provide guidance on how to combine these vectors of references into a vector of values without consuming the iterator? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you actually want *all* combinations of the two vecs? Your current code produces a subset of possible combinations.

Comment: I've already read the duplicate link and best answer and 2nd best one does not work in this situation...

Comment: @Dogbert It seems not working.
https://gist.github.com/azriel1rf/c5521940d470d612b2d9e85d0e1c197d

Comment: @Azriel1rf try `sub_a.iter().cloned().chain(sub_b).cloned().collect()`

Comment: @Dogbert Thanks, it worked. Is `iter().cloned()` more efficient than `clone().into_iter()`, right?

Comment: @Azriel1rf Yes it is (it doesn't clone the vector, only on the fly). But do you need to consume `A` or `B` (or both)? Currently you consume `B` but not `A`.

Comment: What do you mean y "when using a double loop"? Anyway, what I had in mind was something like `A.iter().chain(&B).copied().copied()`

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thank you so much. I got it. If both are consumed, the code is as follows? `A.into_iter().chain(B).cloned().collect()`

Comment: @Azriel1rf Yes (you can replace `cloned()` with `copied()`).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I got it. The `copy` is better than `clone` in this situation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31012923/what-is-the-difference-between-copy-and-clone

Comment: @Azriel1rf I expect both to be optimized to the same machine code, but I prefer `copied()` because it's more explicit (and may, though rarely, be faster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ChayimFriedman, the issue was resolved by using the `copied()` method twice in the chain. The `copied()` method creates an iterator that copies the elements of the original iterator. In this case, it's used to copy the references from the original vectors `a` and `b` into the new vector `c`.

Here's the corrected code:

```rust
// a: Vec<&u8>
// b: Vec<&u8>

let c: Vec<u8> = a.iter().chain(&b).copied().copied().collect();
println!("a: {:?}", a);
println!("b: {:?}", b);
```