# How can I concatenate two slices or two vectors and still have access to the original values?

Tags: vector, rust, append, slice

I have two slice or vectors and I want to add them, as demonstrated here in Golang:

```go
a := []byte{1, 2, 3}
b := []byte{4, 5, 6}
ab := append(a, b...)
ba := append(b, a...)
```

How can I do that in Rust? I found some other questions, such as:

- [What's the idiomatic way to append a slice to a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998515/whats-the-idiomatic-way-to-append-a-slice-to-a-vector)
- [Best way to concatenate vectors in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40792801/best-way-to-concatenate-vectors-in-rust)

but, all of their best answer is `a += b`, and not `ab = a + b`.

```
let mut a = vec![1, 2, 3];
let mut b = vec![4, 5, 6];

a.append(&mut b);

assert_eq!(a, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
assert_eq!(b, []);
```

Or is there maybe a function like `Vec::append(a, b)` in Rust?

Comment: Can you please explain what your desired output is? What is wrong with the example code you were giving? What do you want to look `a` and `b` in the end? Do you want a new vector without modifying the others?

Comment: @hellow I want var ab and var ba, how can i do??

Comment: Can you please answer my question and not asking a new one.

Comment: I want, ab = a + b, not a = a + b

Comment: Please answer **all** of my questions, because it is important on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you want a new vector without modifying the others? I think should Yes.

Answer (score 7):

You can [`chain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.chain) your iterators:

```
fn main() {
    let a = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let b = vec![4, 5, 6];

    // Don't consume the original vectors and clone the items:
    let ab: Vec<_> = a.iter().chain(&b).cloned().collect();

    // Consume the original vectors. The items do not need to be cloneable:
    let ba: Vec<_> = b.into_iter().chain(a).collect();

    assert_eq!(ab, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
    assert_eq!(ba, [4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]);
}
```

Note that the iterator knows the number of items that it yields, so that `collect` can allocate directly the right amount of memory:

```
fn main() {
    let a = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let b = vec![4, 5, 6];

    let ba = b.into_iter().chain(a);
    assert_eq!(ba.size_hint(), (6, Some(6)));

    let ba: Vec<_> = ba.collect();
    assert_eq!(ba, [4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no constructor of [Vec](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) directly appending two slices.

The functionality is not fundamental, as you can implement it yourself:

```
let ab = {
    let mut r = a.clone();
    r.extend_from_slice(&b);
    r
};
```

If you often find yourself performing this operation, you may prefer to write a function to do so:

```
fn cat<T: Clone>(a: &[T], b: &[T]) -> Vec<T> {
    let mut v = Vec::with_capacity(a.len() + b.len());
    v.extend_from_slice(a);
    v.extend_from_slice(b);
    v
}
```

And then you'll be able to do: `let ab = cat(&a, &b);`.